How delete DNS by command prompt?
I just created acsetdns.cmd file to set DNS:
setdns.cmd
@cls
@set /p primary="Enter Primary dns : "
@set /p alternative="Enter Alternative name : "
@netsh interface ip set dns "Wi-Fi" static %primary%
@netsh interface ip add dns name="Wi-Fi" addr="%alternative%" index=2
@pause

Now I'm trying to make a delete.cmd to delete DNS but I do not know how to delete DNS by command.
delete.cmd
some command here ???

I tried these commands but it didn't work:
netsh interface ip set dns "Wi-Fi" static "Empty"
netsh interface ip delete dns "Wi-Fi" static all


If you're just going to shell out to netsh this belongs on superuser.

What exactly do you mean with "delete" the DNS? There are only two options: 1 Get DNS automatically from a DHCP server or 2 set the DNS server manually. You can choose the option to set the DNS server manually and set it up with some local IP that doesn't really do the job, but you have to be aware that your internet will not work without a working DNS server. If you have the option set to manually set DNS and you provide no DNS it automatically switches from manually to get DNS from DHCP server.

you just answer the question netsh interface ip set dns "Wi-Fi" static address="" that is what i looking for pls posted as Answer

If you choose the option to set the DNS manually and provide no DNS that would automatically switch to the option "Get DNS automatically from a DHCP server. If you provide a fake DNS your internet will stop working but the option set DNS manually would still be enabled.
So you could use any of these commands to "Remove" the manually provided DNS servers and switch to "Get DNS from DHCP server automatically":
netsh interface IPv4 set dnsservers "Wi-Fi" source=DHCP
netsh interface ip delete dnsservers name="Wi-Fi" all
netsh interface ipv4 set dnsservers "Wi-Fi" source=static address=""

This removes the manually set DNS servers from the current enabled connection not necessarily wi-fi:
wmic nicconfig where (IPEnabled=TRUE) call SetDNSServerSearchOrder ()

All commands above request admin rights, if you get return value=0 form the wmic command that means all ok, else something went wrong...
